# What is the best practice when declaring a user defined array?

Tags: c, arrays

What's the best practice when having a user defined array? By user defined, I mean size as well as the element values.

Option A:
Predefine an array of size (lets say) 100, then ask the user how many elements they would like in the array, knowing it will be less than what I have defined.

```
int array [100];

printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: ");
scanf("%d", &numElements);
```

Option B:
Declare the array after I ask the user how many elements.

```
printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: ");
scanf("%d", &numElements);

int array [numElements];
```

With option A, it could take up unnecessary memory, but I'm not sure when the cons are with Option B, would it be runtime?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.  Best practice is asking for an opinion which is off topic here.

Comment: Note: VLA are optional in C11,c17

Comment: Are you asking about C, or C++? Option B isn't possible in C++.

Comment: The cons are that in c++ there is NO variable-length arrays, some compilers support this option as an extention, but it is not standard, don't use it there. C++ is about heap allocation via `new` or containers like `std::vector`. If you are into Pure C, choose depending on the performance & your task.

Comment: Since you tagged C++, the best practice is to use `std::vector`.  If you must, the next best choice is `std::array`.

Comment: Please specify only the language you are using, C or C++.

Comment: The C++ tag has been removed, but not by the OP.

Comment: Note that `int array [numElements];` is valid C but not standard C++. For C++ the answer would be different. Better do not tag both when the question is not about interoperation between those two different languages

Comment: Option B may cause a stack overflow if the user enters a large number. Use only option A or B if you can guarantee that size of the array stay small. Otherwise use option C: `malloc()`

Comment: "best practice" includes: do not trust user input.  Test range before using `numElements`.

Answer (score 2):

As it is tagged C, I will try to answer in the scope of C language.
The second case I think is more prefered than the first one. First of all, for the first case, your array will have constant size and you cannot do realloc on it if a user gives input let's say more than 100, as you will get an error that int[100] is not assignable. For the second case, it is assumed that the given input is the sufficient size to create a constant size array because for the same reasons you cannot realloc to change the size of the array but at least you know the input is given by the user.
My suggestion would be to use a dynamic array which is a bit harder to manipulate as you may have memory leaks, for example, when the elements in your dynamic array are not primitive types but structs or other types that require memory allocation.
However, using dynamic array, you can realloc the size to make it bigger or smaller to save some memory space.
I am new to Stack Overflow so maybe your question is something deeper that my answer will not be enough. BTW, I hope it will give you some hint.

P.S.
Static arrays are always faster to be used, so if you are sure that the number of elements will not be more than a certain number, then it is better to use constant size array.

Comment: "...you will get an error that array[100] is not assignable". Correction: You will likely get no such error, only some weird effect in your program that will be a PITA to debug.

Comment: Actually it will not compile, in my opinion, because from C11, the assignment operator should have a modifiable lvalue as the left operand. Modifiable lvalue means lvalue that does not have an array type.

Comment: An array element is very often not of array type

Comment: It was not about the element type in the array, it is about the assignment operator which requires lvalue which is modifiable on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

## if using C++ :

{

The best practice is to use the `std::vector` from the Standard Template Library(STL).

Use `reserve()` and `resize()` methods to allocate fixed required space or `push_back()` and `pop_back()` to resize according to each insertion and deletion. More about vectors [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

}

## else if using C :

{

Use dynamic memory allocation to change the size during runtime using `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `free()` and `realloc()` defined in **`<stdlib.h>`**.

- `malloc()` is used to dynamically allocate a single large block of memory with the specified size. It returns a pointer of type void which can be cast into a pointer of any form.

  ```
  Syntax:
  ptr = (cast-type*) malloc(nbyte-size);
  ```
- `calloc()` is used to dynamically allocate the specified number of blocks of memory of the specified type. It initializes each block with a default value ‘0’.

  ```
  Syntax:
  ptr = (cast-type*)calloc(n, element-size);
  ```

  where **n** is the number of elements required.
- `free()` is used to dynamically de-allocate the memory. The memory allocated using functions `malloc()` and `calloc()` is not de-allocated on their own. Hence the free() method is used, whenever the dynamic memory allocation takes place.

  ```
  Syntax:
  free(ptr);
  ```
- `realloc()` is used to dynamically change the memory allocation of a previously allocated memory. If the memory previously allocated with the help of `malloc()` or `calloc()` is insufficient, `realloc()` can be used to dynamically re-allocate memory.

  ```
  Syntax:
  ptr = realloc(ptr, newSize);
  ```

}